# Lp Convergence of Fourier Integrals Using Hilbert Transform

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space, dirichlet-convolution

I am reading about Hilbert transform and its application on Fourier analyisis, and I am triying to prove a statement given by Terence Tao in his notes on Fourier Analysis. He says that if $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ (Schwartz space), then
$$\int_{-R}^R\hat{\varphi}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}\, d\xi\to\varphi\text{ in }L^p(\mathbb{R}) \text{ with } 1<p<\infty, \text{ as } R\to\infty.$$
The hint given in the proof suggests to use the dominated convergence theorem. Obviously, from the inversion formula follows the pointwise convergence because $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function, but I don't know how to find a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that for a.e point $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\left|{\int_{-R}^R\hat{\varphi}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}\, d\xi}\right|\leq |f(x)|.$$
The link where  notes can be found is [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf) , and the statement is in page 9. Thanks four your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick a constant $M>0$. For $|x|\leq M$, the left-hand side is dominated by $\|\hat \varphi\|_1$.

For $|x|>M$, integrate by parts:
$$\begin{split}
\left|{\int_{-R}^R\hat{\varphi}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}\, d\xi}\right| &= \left| \frac{e^{2i\pi xR}\hat \varphi(R) - e^{-2i\pi xR}\hat \varphi(-R)}{2i\pi x}- \frac 1 {2i\pi x}\int_{-R}^R\hat{\varphi}^\prime(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}\, d\xi\right|\\
&\leq \frac{2\|\hat\varphi\|_\infty+\|\hat\varphi^\prime\|_1}{2\pi |x|}
\end{split}$$
and $x\mapsto \mathbb 1_{|x|>M}\cdot \frac 1 x$ is in $L^p$ for $p>1$.
This is a form of the Riemman-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: Hello, Stefan Lafon. Thank you very much!. I don't know how I didn't think of that jaja.

Comment: No worries,  Riemman-Lebesgue is powerful :)